# How to grant access to create a new file?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

With a PowerShell script I try to create a new file as follows:

```
New-Item -Path $LogDir -Value $LogName -Force -ItemType File
```

which is refused with the following error messsage:

```
New-Item : Access to the path 'D:\Testing\Data\Powershell\Log' is denied.
At D:\Testing\Data\Powershell\LoadRunner\LRmain.ps1:27 char:9
+ New-Item <<<<  -Path $LogDir -Value $LogName -Force -ItemType File
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (D:\Testing\Data\Powershell\Log:String) [New-Item], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NewItemUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand
```

I am executing the script in an Administrator PowerShell 2.0 window on Windows Server 2008. The directory exists, but how can I fix this error?

Comment: I guess thats it ... thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll add @PetSerAl's answer so we can close this question.

You've used the wrong parameter for the filename. Replace `-Value` with `-Name`, ex:

```
New-Item -Path $LogDir -Name $LogName -Force -ItemType File
```